# Merge two Lists of different size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an issue with some part of my code, I'm fetching two apis and then mixing the results in one array:

Initialy the two arrays seems like this (although they can be empty or with more or less data):

```
print(foo)
    [[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 , 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2$ 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2$ 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1], [2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, $, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2]]

print(bar)
    [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [2, 0,
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2]]
```

Their shapes are:

```
foo --> (7,) (the 2nd dimension varies on shape so numpy doesn't get it)
bar --> (7, 20) (In this case the sublists len() matches, but maybe won't in the future)
[len(i) for i in foo] --> [94, 95, 96, 96, 97, 96, 95] # not all sublists are equal in length
[len(i) for i in bar] --> [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
```

So of course, when I try to append them in the 2nd dimension:

```
df = np.hstack([foo, bar]).tolist()
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

My question is what would be the best solution to this, trying to not loose data, maybe appending each sublist manually work but is it the only solution I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One array only has 1 dimension, the other has 2. But you can quickly adjust the first array to have dimensions (7,1) by using `newaxis`

For example:

```
df = np.hstack([foo[:, np.newaxis], bar]).tolist()
```